# Set background color for a specific text in a XML TextView using CDATA

Tags: android, textview, android-xml, cdata

I can able to set text color using CDATA.

```
<string name="sample">
<![CDATA[ This is <font color=#ff0000>Red color</font>]]>
</string>
```

But how can i able to set backgound color to highlight the text?

Example:  This is `RedColor`

Can anyone help me?

Comment: You could use Spannable, I think that you can't do it in HTML. Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20920329/html-fromhtml-not-working-with-background-color-of-text